# "Mir fallen keine solche(n) ein" - mit oder ohne n?

Tags: inflection

Im Zuge einer anderen Diskussion in diesem schönen Forum bin ich auf eine Unsicherheit gestoßen, die ich offenbar bei den Kasusendungen von "solch" habe.

Hier mein Beispielsatz:

> Die These ist hübsch, aber um sie zu akzeptieren bräuchte ich weitere Evidenz, etwa Hinweise auf die Verwendung des Wortes in anderen Kontexten. Mir fallen aber keine **solche** ein.

Dies hingeschrieben habend fing ich an zu zweifeln. Müsste es nicht

> Mir fallen aber keine solche**n** ein

heißen? Aber wenn, dann wieso? "Solche" ist hier Subjekt, darum im Nominativ. Wer fällt mir nicht ein? Solche fallen mir nicht ein! Ich würde auch nicht sagen: "Solchen fallen mir nicht ein."

Frage: Wo liegt der Pudel im Pfeffer? Was ist des Hasen Kern? Gibt es eine Regel? Ist beides möglich?

Comment: +1 für den gepfefferten Pudel :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es handelt sich um die [gemischte Flexion von *solch*](http://canoonet.eu/inflection/solch:A:Demonstr) im Nominativ Plural:

> Mir fallen keine solchen (Beispiele) ein.

Zur Komplettierung noch Beispiele für die übrigen Kasus:

> - Akkusativ: *Ich gebe keine solchen (Beispiele) zum Besten.*
> - Dativ: *Ich glaube keinen solchen (Aussagen).*
> - Genitiv: *Ich komme keiner solchen (Beispiele) wegen.*

Den Kasus sieht man besser, wenn man im Singular flektiert:

> Mir fällt kein solches (Beispiel *n.*) ein.
>   Mir fällt keine solche (Umschreibung *f.*) ein.
>   Mir fällt kein solcher (Begriff *m.*) ein.

Comment: Vielen Dank. Aus der verlinkten Quelle entnehme ich noch, dass die "gemischte Flexion" von *solch* gilt, wenn es mit *ein*, *kein*, Possesivpronomen u.a. auftritt. Wobei mich jetzt interessieren würde, was "u.a." konkret meint.

Comment: Ich muss gestehen, dass mir das völlig neu war. Man lernt nie aus ...

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: *u.a.* ist mir auch schleierhaft... vielleicht stoßen wir mal versehntlich drauf und erinnern uns - Jedenfalls finde ich die Canoo Tabellen immer super hilfreich!

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann - u.a. - alle (allen solchen), wenig (wenigen solchen), etc. es wird noch einige Wörter geben.